# Android 7 Bluetooth intermittent disconnecting

Tags: bluetooth

Android 7 phone once paired with earphones or car headset disconnects and reconnect, causing annoying drops in music play

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to **Location settings**, put *mode* in **Battery saving** mode. This helps with battery drain. Then press the *3-dots* -> select **Scanning** -> disable **Bluetooth scanning** and also disable **WiFi scanning**.
2. Go to **Battery** -> click *3-dots* -> **Optimization**. Select **All apps**, then don't optimize **BT tool**.

Comment: Amazing, this helped me a lot! Especially the third point with disabling the optimization for BT tool, now my headset isn't dropping out anymore. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My HUAWEI 3a  drops off the car phone system. I had replaced the car system to overcome this issue previously but it still did it.

Eventually found that when the phone went to sleep (in my case 2 min) it shut the bluetooth down and any calls ceased.

I reset the phone to 30 min which is the longest it goes to and now no problems.